# How can I bulk insert?

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, prepared-statement, teradata

I want to insert data to TERADATA with jdbc.But it is slow. How can I make it faster?

I wrote this code:

```
connection_tera= DriverManager.getConnection
             (
             "jdbc:teradata://192.168.x.xx/database=DBC,tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8","dbc","dbc"
             ); 

stmt_tera = connection_tera.prepareStatement("insert into a.b values(?)");
//some code here to start while loop 
  stmt_tera.setObject(i,reset.getobject(i));
  stmt_tera.addBatch();  
 if(addedBatchNumber%100==0)
  stmt_tera.executeBatch(); 
  connection_tera.commit(); 
  stmt_tera.clearBatch();
//some code here and finish while loop
```

Should I add paramater like TYPE=FASTLOAD to connection string? or something else?

Comment: bulk operation are usually is configured at db system, but maybe disabling the index at the target table would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are loading to an **empty** table I would consider using JDBC FastLoad. For more details on the performance of JDBC to insert data into a Teradata table please refer to the following article on the Teradata Developer Exchange: [**Speed up your JDBC/ODBC Applications**](http://developer.teradata.com/connectivity/articles/speed-up-your-jdbcodbc-applications)

If your table is not empty, it may make sense to load the data to a staging (intermediate) table that is empty first. Then use the ANSI `MERGE` operation to apply the `INSERT/UPDATE` logic to the target table. The `MERGE` operation will perform faster than the traditional `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements because the operation works at the block level instead of row level. In some instances you can even avoid spooling the source data before the data is applied to the target table.

Here is a [**collection**](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samplePrograms.html) of sample Teradata JDBC Driver programs. Programs 205 through 209 are examples of using FastLoad.

Comment: thanks for reply,I am loading to empty table. I use `Batch Ready` in that site but it is still slow. But I cant try the `Full Speed Ahead` on that site

Comment: How much data are you loading through this interface? I have added a link to a collection of sample programs to my answer.

Comment: I try to load 415.000 row to TERADA.It takes over 20 minutes

Comment: I edit my question. I execute batch when addedbatch number has 100. But it is still slow. I cant understand. I think some parameter are needed in connection string

Comment: If you are loading 415K records via JDBC it would be in your best interest to use the JDBC FastLoad.

Comment: Thanks for answer but  what you mean about JDBC Fastload?

Comment: when I use TYPE=FASTLOAD in connection string as parameter, I got this error : `HY000 This method is not implemented` this error occurs when I use `executeupdate` but when I use addbacth and exxecutebatch method it doesnot give error but it doesnt repyle just wait when I use debug mode in netbeans.

Comment: Is there any different jdbc driver instead the terajdbc.jar ?

Comment: Did you look at the sample code that I linked to with examples of how to implement a JDBC FastLoad?\

Comment: I looked your samples.jar but I dont see the fastload sample

Answer (score 2):

Additionally you can also consider another side of the coin..Meaning you can think of performing multiple row insert with single query

```
insert into table1 (First,Last) values ('Fred','Smith'),
  ('John','Smith'),
  ('Michael','Smith'),
  ('Robert','Smith');
```

The benefits are

- Connecting/interacting with database is an expensive operation. Say you have to insert 100 rows using your code so you would write your application in such a way to fire 100 quires( 100 db interactions ).. Instead of this, build your sql query as mentioned above and try insert and check the performance.
- You are avoiding n number of database interactions.
- Insert operation is seamlessly faster if you do like this.. This has been widely adopted technique to restore/import databases.

Hope this will be helpful.. 
Cheers!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, you are executing and committing a batch that has only one insert statement in it - I don't think that is your intention ( or, if it is, I think you are misunderstanding how batches are expected to be used )

Seems like you need to have an inner loop that adds an arbitrary number of statements to the batch which you then submit via `executeBatch()`

Comment: Then I think we're heading in the direction Rob is suggesting. It looks like your doing about 350 inserts a second, which strikes me as pretty good for a java / jdbc program, particularly if the database and application are on different servers ( which I don,t think you specify ). Java isn't the perfect tool for every job. By the way, in your code you never increment addedBatchNumber - I'm assumming that's just not shown, otherwise you are still submitting batches consisting of 1 statement. Another option would be to run several threads ( this assumes the bottleneck is in the java )

Comment: How can I do the fastload on jdbc?