# How to specify Fastload utility for jdbc:odbc?

Tags: java, teradata

My connection string looks like this

`String cn = "jdbc:odbc:DSN";`
it works fine . However, when i try to modify it to 
`String cn = "jdbc:odbc:DSN, TYPE=FASTLOAD";` 
it does not establish connection

I also tried
`String cn = "jdbc:odbc:DSN, TYPE=FASTLOADCSV";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
String cn = "jdbc:odbc:DSN; TYPE=FASTLOAD";

Comment: it shud be ; not , :)

Answer (score 3):

Teradata's JDBC driver supports the FastLoad protocol, but you're not using it. You try to connect via JDBC-ODBC bridge, change to **jdbc:teradata://...**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect with ODBC, then use semicolons. But if you want to use FastLoad, then you need to connect using JDBC, in which case you should use commas and the forward slash like so:

```
String cn = "jdbc:teradata://servername/TYPE=FASTLOADCSV";
```

Also, you'll need to disable auto-committing whenever you fastload (at least if you do batch inserting, which you probably should). Fastload requires an empty table; committing causes the table to be non-empty. To prevent that issue, simply set autocommit to False before inserting, and set it back to True (or whatever you want it to be) after all inserts have been executed and committed.

Alternatively, you can pursue a different approach: commit stuff, but use staging tables. With this method you create new, empty tables for each insert batch. In the end you can consolidate those tables into one with the MERGE operation. If you do this process right, you can avoid any rewriting of data on disk. (Source: [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443722/how-can-i-bulk-insert))

More information:

- [Teradata JDBC tips on improving performance](http://developer.teradata.com/connectivity/articles/speed-up-your-jdbcodbc-applications)
- [Sample code from Teradata about JDBC, with boilerplate code on connectivity, CRUD, etc.](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samplePrograms.html)
- [More Teradata docs on connectivity with JDBC](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html)